# How to access SQLite database in androidRecyclerVIew?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-connection, android-cardview

I've created a SQLite database which contains two columns: "title" and "content" and don't have any idea how to display it in my android RecyclerView with two textViews "card_title" and "card_content". please kindly help me with this.
Here is my recycler adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;
    private Context context;





    public List<CardItemModel> cardItems;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<CardItemModel> cardItems){
        this.cardItems = cardItems;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView copyButton;
        ImageView shareButton;
        ToggleButton favButton;



        TextView title;
        TextView content;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            this.content = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_content);
            this.copyButton= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.copyButton);
            this.shareButton=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

            this.favButton=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favButton);

            favButton.setChecked(false);
            favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));


        }
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(cardItems.get(position).title);
        holder.content.setText(cardItems.get(position).content);
        holder.copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){


                myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", holder.content.getText().toString());
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }
        });
        holder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, holder.content.getText().toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
            }
        });

        holder.favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton favButton, boolean isChecked){
                if (isChecked)
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

                else
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_cart));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardItems.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to retrieve the data from database before loading the recycler view? Because you should retrieve the data, and then create the recycler view by passing the list you retrieved from the db

Answer (score 0):

**try this in your activity before your recyclerview adpter**

**now in your activity**

```
ArrayList<String> title
ArrayList<String> content
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

content= new ArrayList<>();
title= new ArrayList<>();
```

**now get data from sqlite and add into arraylist**

```
  myDatabase = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("user_master",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);

    Cursor c=myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_master", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        title.add(c.getString(0));
        content.add(c.getString(2));


    }
```

**now set recyclerview adapter**

```
   RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new DataAdapter(title,content);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write down this function in your Activity

```
public ArrayList<CardItemModel> getAllElements() {

    List<CardItemModel> cardItems = new ArrayList<>();       
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

     try {

            try {

             // looping through all rows and adding to list

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        CardItemModel obj = new CardItemModel();

                        //only one column
                        obj.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                        obj.setContent(cursor.getString(1));

                        //you could add additional columns here..

                        cardItems.add(obj);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

            } finally {
                try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }

        } finally {
             try { db.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }
        return cardItems;
}
```

in onCreate method of Activity call this function

```
List<CardItemModel> cardItems = getAllElements();
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(cardItems);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```